# Can someone explain me the working of the code? This code is supposed to print the reverse of a number

Tags: c, for-loop, output

// C program to print reverse of a number using for loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
long int num,i;
int d;
printf("\n enter number");
scanf("%ld",&num);
printf("\n the reverse of number %ld is ",num);
     for(i=0;num>0;i++)
{
       d=num%10;
       num=num/10;
       printf("%d",d);

 }

  return 0;
}
```

I think there is no terminating given in this code as the for loop will run infinte times, but this code is working fine, so can someone explain this code?

Comment: You are printing the least significant digit of `num` in each loop, and dividing it by `10`. It reaches `0` eventually. The loop ends. `i` is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Comment: `for(;num>0;)` will do just fine here.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand the loop you need to understand the working of % 10 and /= 10 operations.

The first one, the remainder of division by ten, chops off the last decimal digit. The second one drops that digit from the number, because the division is done in integers.

Dividing a number by ten repeatedly will make it a zero aftre a number of iterations equal to the number of digits in the number, so that is when your loop is going to stop.